# Aligning Multiple Polygons (Based on centroid possibly) [Spatstat, sf, sp]

Tags: r, sf, sp, spatstat

I'm trying to create a composite/average of multiple similarly shaped polygons. I think the first step is most likely to align them via the centroid of each polygon.

Does anybody know of a tool to align polygons in R? I am using spatstat mainly, but can convert the polygons to sp and sf classes.

Here's an example of what I have so far:

```
test.verts <- list()
test.verts$x <- c(518, 594, 421, 286, 104, 129, 315)
test.verts$y <- c(273, 608, 1202, 1201, 620, 285, 135)

test.verts2 <- list()
test.verts2$x <- c(900, 922, 693, 471, 207, 305, 628)
test.verts2$y <- c(459, 777, 1265, 1267, 615, 325, 135)

test.verts3 <- list()
test.verts3$x <- c(910, 980, 687, 476, 223, 389, 664)
test.verts3$y <- c(343, 863, 1339, 1340, 594, 185, 65)

test.owin <- spatstat::owin(poly = test.verts)
test.owin2 <- spatstat::owin(poly = test.verts2)
test.owin3 <- spatstat::owin(poly = test.verts3)

plot(test.owin)
plot(test.owin2, add = TRUE)
plot(test.owin3, add = TRUE)
```

[image: Three polygons, similar in shape, with unequal sizes]

The figure cuts of some parts of the polygons due to size. The polygons are roughly the same shape, but vary somewhat in size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `centroid.owin` to find the centroid of an `owin` and `shift` to translate an `owin`.

Let's put your polys in a list:

```
> polys = list(test.owin, test.owin2, test.owin3)
```

And shift them all to have centroid (0,0):

```
> zpolys = lapply(polys, function(p){ce=centroid.owin(p);shift(p,c(-ce$x, -ce$y))})

> plot(zpolys[[3]])
> 
> plot(zpolys[[2]],add=TRUE)
> plot(zpolys[[1]],add=TRUE)
```

[image]

If you want to shift them somewhere else then adjust the offset to suit. For example you could work out the mean of the centroids, then shift by the individual centroids minus the mean. Or shift everything to (0,0) as above and then shift everything again by (xmean, ymean). I shifted things to (0,0) because its easier to then scale things when centred at (0,0), which I have a hunch is what you might want to do next...

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Do you know of any methods for "averaging" the polygons into one polygon that can then be converted to an owin?

Comment: That's a very different question that probably requires a more precise definition of "average" than sticking it in quote marks and hoping! It all depends on your application... Interesting question though, if you can flesh it out into a new post, please do...